# Add data to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem here with bootstrap modals, so in back-end of my app I pull out data from SQL, and I call a JS function like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowPopup",
                   "MailLanguageChange('" + Description + "','" + TextResult + "');", true);
```

And JS looks like this :

```
function MailLanguageChange(Name, Text) {
        $('#MainContent_NewMailTemplate').modal('show');

        document.getElementById("Upper_txtDesc").value = Name;
        document.getElementById("TextEditorTextArea").innerHTML = Text;
    }
```

So firebug hits break point at this function, so I am sure call of function does work, but here comes the problem, JS is trying to apply this data onto the modal, before all elements of modal are loaded.

But as I use this modal for multiple purpuses ... is there anyway to write it down, "Don't do anything until modal is shown"?

```
 $('#MainContent_NewMailTemplate').modal('show');
```

As docs says, it returns to the caller before the modal has actually been shown ... how can i by pass that?

**EDIT** :

This is how I have also tried it

```
function MailLanguageChange(Name, Text) {

        $('#MainContent_NewMailTemplate').modal('show');

        $("#MainContent_NewMailTemplate").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            document.getElementById("Upper_txtDesc").value = Name;
            document.getElementById("TextEditorTextArea").innerHTML = Text;
        });
    }
```

**CONCLUSION :**

With use of logic of global variables provided by @Guruprasad Rao 
I ended up just simply using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("Upper_txtDesc").value = name;
    document.getElementById("TextEditorTextArea").innerHTML = text;
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `twitter-bootstrap's` `shown.bs.modal` method as below:

```
$("#yourmodalid").on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
   //Do whatever you want here
});
```

There are several other <kbd>**[`events`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)**</kbd> to look into regarding `modal`

[image]

---

**Update**

see you are showing the `modal` first and then you are registering that event.. So I would suggest you below steps.

> - Declare 2 global variables at the top in js page.

**Ex**

```
var name,text;
```

> - Assign them values inside your `function MailLanguageChange`.

**Ex**

```
function MailLanguageChange(Name, Text) {
    name=Name;
    text=Text;
    $('#MainContent_NewMailTemplate').modal('show');
}
```

> - Keep `shown.bs.modal` event somewhere outside the above `function`

**Ex**

```
$("#MainContent_NewMailTemplate").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     document.getElementById("Upper_txtDesc").value = name;
     document.getElementById("TextEditorTextArea").innerHTML = text;
});
```

Comment: I seen that, but for some reason firebug doesn't go inside of that function .. that's my problem

Comment: Can you show us how you've used it and on what actual situations? Does you view containing `modal` load through `ajax`?

Comment: I edit a question, not using AJAX here, just calling JS function on post back of my C# page

Comment: Updated answer.. Check it and let me know.. If it doesn't work then move the `event` registering inside the function before `modal show`

Comment: Yep ... it works the way you told me ... i really messed up the way I was creating that modal, problem was that my "TextEditorTextArea" is acting like not part of modal ... that's why it didn't get value of innerHTML ... thank you man!

Comment: No probs.. Happy coding.. :)